# designing a pcb breakout board with micro dsubs

Tags: pcb-design

I am a beginner in the world of pcbs and I'd like to make a breakout board. The board will be breaking out signals from micro dsubs. There are no other components on the board.

What is the simplest software for me to use? I looked at multisim and orcad(I have working licenses for both) but I couldnt find the micro dsub connector available.

Is there some connector database I am not aware of for those two software suites?
Otherwise, what free alternative should I look at? Should I be making the connectors myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just my opinion, but you don't get very far in any package without learning how to add parts to the libraries, and that once you know it, making the parts on your own is marginally faster and more reliable than finding it on some database.

Sometimes you get lucky, and the part manufacturer will actually provide engineering files that can be opened or imported into your CAD program (sometimes using Ultralibrarian)

Comment: +1. If you actually are serious about design work, you should check the symbol & footprint before using. At this point you may as well draw them yourself, it's as quick and has advantage of using your own design routines & habits for that extra bit of polish.

Comment: @Hans-- absolutely.  That's why I like making my own.  Validation doesn't seem to take as long